# How to handle the checkboxes in pysimplegui with if statements

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, pysimplegui

I am working with `pysimplegui` I am trying to handle the `checkboxes` chosen by the users. I wonder why my `if-statements` are working against what I designed them do. What could I possibly be doing wrong.

See the area of focus below:

```
 if event == "Export Options":
        
        try:
            export_window_layout = [
                [sg.Frame(
                            layout=[
                                [sg.Checkbox('PDF', default=True, key='pdf_export'),  
                                sg.Checkbox('Excel', key='excel_export'),
                                sg.Checkbox('HTML file', key='html_export')],
                                ], 
                            title='Select file types',
                            title_color='white', 
                            relief=sg.RELIEF_SUNKEN, 
                            tooltip='Select the formats you would like to export')],
                 
                [sg.Button('Export'), sg.Button('Cancel')]]
        
            export_window = sg.Window("Export Options", export_window_layout)
        

            while True:
            
                export_event, export_values = export_window.read()
                print(f"export events: {export_event} \n export values: {export_values}")
            
                if export_event in (None, 'Cancel'):
                    break

                           
                # if a user selects PDF format only
                if not (export_values['excel_export'] and export_values['html_export']):
                    
                   try:
                       print("You selected PDF only")
                       
                       break
                       
                   except:
                       sg.popup("There was an issue with the export!")
                       break
                       
                    
                # if a user selects PDF and excel only
                if not export_values['html_export']:
                    try: 

                        sg.popup("You have selected pdf and excel")
                    
                    except:
                        sg.popup_error("There was an issue with the export!")

                    break               

                # if a user selects PDF and HTML only
                if not export_values['excel_export']:
                    try: 
                        sg.popup("You have selected pdf and HTML")
                    
                    except:
                        sg.popup_error("There was an issue with the export!")

                    break                
            
                # if a user selects ALL files
                if (export_values['pdf_export'] and export_values['excel_export'] and export_values['html_export']):
                    try: 
                        print("You are in the ALL files area")
                        sg.popup("You have selected ALL files")
                    
                    except:
                        sg.popup_error("There was an issue with the export!")

                    break
            
                # if a user selects excel only
                if not (export_values['pdf_export'] and export_values['html_export']):
                    try: 
                        sg.popup("You have selected Excel only")
                    
                    except:
                        sg.popup_error("There was an issue with the export!")

                    break          

                # if a user selects HTML only
                if not (export_values['pdf_export'] and export_values['excel_export']):
                    try: 
                        sg.popup("You have selected HTML only")
                    
                    except:
                        sg.popup_error("There was an issue with the export!")

                    break

                # if a user selects excel and HTML
                if not export_values['pdf_export']:
                    try: 

                        sg.popup("You have selected Excel and HTML")
                    
                    except:
                        sg.popup_error("There was an issue with the export!")

                    break
                                
            export_window.Close()
            
        except:
            sg.popup("You must pass STEP ONE & TWO before EXPORTING")
```

The problem is that the program is not behaving as intended. If I select HTML and EXCEL, it shows a different loop block.

Here is the kind of output the export_values shows `{"pdf_export": True, "excel_export": False, "html_export": False}`

I welcome an elegant way to refactor my code to improve readability as well as fixing the issue at hand.

Answer (score 1):

Change Your Code with this code, maybe this will work for you:

```
if event == "Export Options":
        
        try:
            export_window_layout = [
                [sg.Frame(
                            layout=[
                                [sg.Checkbox('PDF', default=True, key='pdf_export'),  
                                sg.Checkbox('Excel', key='excel_export'),
                                sg.Checkbox('HTML file', key='html_export')],
                                ], 
                            title='Select file types',
                            title_color='white', 
                            relief=sg.RELIEF_SUNKEN, 
                            tooltip='Select the formats you would like to export')],
                 
                [sg.Button('Export'), sg.Button('Cancel')]]
        
            export_window = sg.Window("Export Options", export_window_layout)
        

            while True:
            
                export_event, export_values = export_window.read()
                print(f"export events: {export_event} \n export values: {export_values}")
            
                if export_event in (None, 'Cancel'):
                    break

                           
                # if a user selects PDF format only
                if export_values['excel_export'] == False and export_values['html_export'] == False:
                   try:
                       sg.popup("You selected PDF only")
                       break
                   except:
                       sg.popup("There was an issue with the export!")
                       break

                # if a user selects excel only
                elif export_values['pdf_export'] == False and export_values['html_export'] == False:
                    try: 
                        sg.popup("You have selected Excel only")
                    except:
                        sg.popup_error("There was an issue with the export!")
                    break  

                # if a user selects HTML only
                elif export_values['pdf_export'] == False and export_values['excel_export'] == False:
                    try: 
                        sg.popup("You have selected HTML only")
                    except:
                        sg.popup_error("There was an issue with the export!")
                    break
                    
                # if a user selects PDF and excel only
                elif export_values['html_export'] == False:
                    try: 
                        sg.popup("You have selected pdf and excel")
                    
                    except:
                        sg.popup_error("There was an issue with the export!")
                    break               

                # if a user selects PDF and HTML only
                elif export_values['excel_export'] == False:
                    try: 
                        sg.popup("You have selected pdf and HTML")
                    except:
                        sg.popup_error("There was an issue with the export!")
                    break    

                # if a user selects excel and HTML
                if export_values['pdf_export'] == False:
                    try:
                        sg.popup("You have selected Excel and HTML")
                    except:
                        sg.popup_error("There was an issue with the export!")
                    break            
            
                # if a user selects ALL files
                else : 
                    try: 
                        print("You are in the ALL files area")
                        sg.popup("You have selected ALL files")
                    except:
                        sg.popup_error("There was an issue with the export!")
                    break

            export_window.Close()
            
        except:
            sg.popup("You must pass STEP ONE & TWO before EXPORTING")
```